# Parse open source server sending push using cloud

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I am now on the new parse open source server and I am trying to send a push notification using the cloud `main.js`. I sent a push using curl but can not in the .js file. Here is the code I have.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("PushNotification", function(request, response) {
  console.log('sending push');
var Installation = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  console.log(Installation);

Parse.Push.send({

    where: Installation,
  data: {
    alert: request.params.Message,
    badge: 0,
    sound: 'default'
  }
}, {
  useMasterKey: true,
  success: function() {
    // Push sent!
  console.log('Push sent');
        response.success('success');

  },
  error: function(error) {
    // There was a problem :(
          response.error("Error push did not send");
            console.log('sending push error: '+error);


  }
});
```

It says that it sent but It did not. If any one could help that would be great!

Comment: If it says it sent, the error may be on your client side.  Have you checked your Manifest file to ensure that everything is as it should be?

Comment: @A.Vin I can send it using curl but not javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a answer on [github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1740#issuecomment-218506893) and I hope this will help any one else with the same problem. Here is the code I used.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("PushNotification", function(request, response) {
      console.log('sending push');
    var Installation = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      console.log(Installation);

    Parse.Push.send({
    useMasterKey: true,
        where: Installation,
      data: {
//or you can put "" to not do a custom alert
        alert: request.params.Message,
        badge: 0,
        sound: 'default'
      }
    }, {
      useMasterKey: true,
      success: function() {
        // Push sent!
      console.log('Push sent');
            response.success('success');

      },
      error: function(error){
    console.error(error);
    }

    });
    });
```

Comment: I am assuming now if i am using swift ios app i can call this cloud code function just passing in the message as a param and it will send to the correct user?

Comment: @kareem this code I am using sends to all the users. The code for sending it using swift is in the parse docs.